# regex percentage with 8 decimal points after the comma

Tags: c#, regex, devexpress

I want to manage the inserted percentage value over a regex "function" and it should looks like this:

> 0,00000000
>
> 99,99900000
>
> or 100,10000000

I've tried to do it with the following regex but it wount work, have someone a solution to solve the "problem" ?  The percentage value should always have 8 decimal points after the comma

```
this.Percentage.AutoHeight = false;
this.Percentage.Mask.EditMask = "(100(\\R.0{1,2})?)|((\\d{1,2}(\\R.\\d{1,8})?))";
this.Percentage.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.RegEx;
this.Percentage.Name = "Percentage";
```

for the ________ after the comma should be 8 time a 0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
^[0-9]+\,[0-9]{8}$
```

With that regex you have a number, with 8 decimal points after the comma: XX...XXX,XXXXXXXX and X is element of {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

To archive that the value before the comma can't be bigger than 100 you have to change the regex into this:

```
^((100)|([1-9]?[0-9]))\,[0-9]{8}$
```

Comment: looks good but it is possible to add all 8 decimal points in the beginning with a 0 and that the user can't add more than 100 before the comma ? so that 101,.... is not possible ?

Comment: Check my edit. But what do you mean with **add all 8 decimal points in the beginning with a 0**?

Comment: Please take a look to the screenshot i've added to my main post.

Comment: This has nothing to do with regex. You have to replace every `_` with `0`

Comment: Did you maybe know were i can do this ? is this a basic setting?

Comment: I don't know what type `0,_________` is, but for a String you can use [replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I think it's a devexpress setting but i have no idea, thanks for all

the type is a string thats right

Comment: @kb_ Unfortunately I am not a C# developer. For the replace you maybe ask a new specific question so that somebody how has experience in that can help you.